# cannot order js function execution using promises

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, promise

Basically, i have to 2 functions A and B to get data from rest, then I want to run function C after successfully get the data

this is my code :

JS:

```
var A = function() {

  $.getJSON('linkA', function(data) {
    a = data.total;
    console.log("A : " + a);
  });

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('Got a');
  });
};

var B = function() {

  $.getJSON('linkB', function(data) {
    b = data.total;
    console.log("B:" + b);
  });

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('Got b');
  });
};

function run() {
  Promise.all([A(), B()]).then(function() {
    console.log("Got A and B")
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<script>
run();
</script>
```

I want the result should be in Console :

A: //data

B:  //data

Got A and B

However , i still got "Got A and B" before the other two lines . I guess because getting data takes quite a long time so the program write the "Got A and B" first. But there is must be someway to get the goal right ??

Comment: You need to put your `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { ...` into  `$.getJSON('linkB', function(data) {...` callback function.

Comment: little bug Promise.all([A, B]).then(function() {
    console.log("Got A and B")
  }); change your code for this

Comment: @Krusader No, OP needs to *resolve* the promise inside the `getJSON` function.

Comment: do i need also put it in getJson('linkA') ?

Comment: Yes like so https://jsfiddle.net/jfpya36a/

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón: No, the OP is correct to *call* `A` and `B`.

Comment: @Krusader i put it inside but still the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're immediately resolving the promises, rather than waiting until you get the data back.

You're also falling prey to the promise creation anti-pattern. [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) *already* gives you a thenable*, so just use it and use `then` to transform the data (by accessing `total`):

```
var A = function() {
  return $.getJSON('linkA').then(function(data) {
    return data.total;
  });
};
```

And the same with `B`. Then your `Promise.all` code will work, and if you tweak it you can actually get `a` and `b`:

```
function run() {
  Promise.all([A(), B()]).then(function(results) {
    var a = results[0], b = results[1];
    // ...use `a` and `b`...
  });
}
```

Or if you can rely on ES2015+ features, you can use an arrow function and destructuring (or a normal function and destructuring if you prefer):

```
function run() {
  Promise.all([A(), B()]).then(([a, b]) => {
    // ...use `a` and `b`...
  });
}
```

Since the rest of your code just relies on jQuery, not Promise support in the browser, you could also use jQuery's `$.when`:

```
function run() {
  $.when(A(), B()).then(function(a, b) {
    // ...use `a` and `b`...
  });
}
```

---

***If*** you needed to explicitly do `new Promise` (you don't here) to interface with a non-thenable API, it would look like this:

```
// YOU DON'T NEED TO DO THIS WITH $.getJSON, but with non-thenable APIs you might
var A = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.getJSON('linkA', function(data) {
      resolve(data.total);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      reject(errorThrown || new Error(textStatus));
    });
  });
};
```

---

* "thenable" - A promise-like thing, see [the Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/).

Comment: so do i need to create 'new promise' inside A and B function ?

Comment: @NgocTuanLam: No, you need to **not** create a new promise within `A` and `B`. After all, you already have one (from `$.getJSON`).

Comment: *Note: If you don't see `then` inside the first code block above, hit refresh.*

Comment: Woa , thank you ,i used your first 2 block of code and it works , However ,assigning using var a = results[0] , b = results[1]; in your second block. What i actually get for a and b is 2 object , not the data . so i fixed it by assign a  and b in A and B function and just console log a and b in the run() function. I will try your other suggestions . Thanks

Comment: @NgocTuanLam: Yeah, I caught that belatedly, it's the reason for my *"Note: If you don't see `then`..."* comment above.

Comment: So to be clear, the reason why the normal promise syntax not working is because of the fact that getJson is also a promise itself ??

Comment: @NgocTuanLam: This *is* normal promise syntax; you don't want to use `new Promise` any time you *already* have a thenable to work with. I addressed why your code wasn't working in the first sentence of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/';

Promise.all( [url + 1, url + 2 ].map( $.get ) )
  .then(
   console.log
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```